# SSH reverse tunnel and port forward to a different machine on remote network

Tags: ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, forwarding, remote-management

i am trying to do something , but i cant get it to work
After at least 4-5 hours of research and trying , its time for help

I want to connect to a second remote machine trough a primary remote machine

my setup is like that

-> "Home1" windows desktop machine with SSH server

-> "HOME" router with opened port to "Home1" SSH server

-> internet

-> "REMOTE" router with port opened to SSH server to "Remote1"

-> "Remote1" on the same LAN as "Remote2"

-> Http Server on port 1080 on "Remote1"

-> Http Server on port 80 on "Remote2"

-> Empty IPTABLE and policy set to ACCEPT on "Remote1"

what is working right now :

- i can connect to SSH console on "Remote1"
- launch reverse SSH tunneling from "Remote1" To "Home1"
  ->   ssh -fN -R 1080:localhost:1080 user@HOMEIP
- i can acces "Remote1" http server from "Home1"  by typing  127.0.0.1:1080 in my browser

SO FAR everything is OK

but if i try to do

```
ssh -fN -R 80:localhost:80 user@HOMEIP
```

then

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

i can never get acces to "Remote2" http server

i get an error on the "Remote1" console everytime i try to acces it thru my browser on "Home1"

```
connect_to localhost port 80: failed.
```

i am sure that "Remote2" is up and running , because it is actually my ISP router and i want to acces it to open new ports (interface acces is only possible from LAN and locked from WAN)
(i have 3 hours of road to "REMOTE" and no one on site for weeks)

also tried many permutation of different settings and nothing seem to work

THANKS

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142624/discussion-on-question-by-antoine-lanaud-ssh-reverse-tunnel-and-port-forward-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Connection to remote2 is in fact working , but it appear that there is a HTTPS certificate problem , did not find how to fix it , but i think this is not related to the original question

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please check the Asking and Answering -sections in the Help. SE communities aren't discussion forums, Answers are strictly for providing answers to questions (yes, you can answer your own too if you find a solution). As this is a separate issue you should delete the answer and ask another question. Please include relevant details of your system / setup. You can also refer to this question in the new one.